# VB.NET right button click event on dynamically created button

Tags: vb.net, events

Similar to: [Get the ID/Name of a button in a click event. VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566156/get-the-id-name-of-a-button-in-a-click-event-vb-net) ?

I am looking to find whether the left or right button was clicked on a mouse.  I have declared a block class which holds buttons.  I've assigned an event to the button click through:

```
Class Block
  Public X As Integer
  Public Y As Integer
  Public type As String
  Public status As String
  Public text As String
  Public WithEvents button As Button

  Private Sub btnReveal_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button.Click
  ....
  ....
  End Sub
```

This works fine, but when I try to pick up the right button click using:

```
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        MessageBox.Show("RH click")
    Else
        button.Text = text
        button.BackColor = Color.LightGray
    End If
```

It complains on e.Button:
     Button is not a member of System.EventArgs

Any ideas?

Comment: The `Click` event doesn't tell you which mouse button (if any) was clicked  So handle the `MouseClick` event. http://stackoverflow.com/a/936615/284240

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handle the [MouseUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup.aspx) or [MouseDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown.aspx) Events. They pass the `MouseEventArgs`.

Comment: So I was just testing to make sure before writing a very similar answer and I find that when I'm handling MouseClick it knows if it's the left button, but not if it's the right.  And if I'm handling the mouseUp event, it knows either way.